# Is there a way I can call a parent class constructor that takes parameters from a child class that does not have a constructor of it's own?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super

As we all know, the parent class must be constructed before the child class; and if the parent's class constructor takes parameters, then the constructor of the parent class must be called explicitly. My question is, how do you call a parent class constructor that takes parameters explicitly from a child class, if the child class does not have a constructor itself?

```
public class A {
public String text;

public A(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}


public class B extends A {
// Now I must call the constructor of A explicitly (other wise I'll get a
// compilation error) but how can I do that without a constructor here?
}
```

Comment: Why would you not want to have a constructor in B?

Comment: If you don't specify why you're looking to not have a constructor in B, this is just an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's just a hypothetical situation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept, and sorry for the confusion around super() and super.someMethod() :-)

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for the answer and for clarifying that every class has a constructor, even if I don't make one explicitly. Knowing the compiler makes one automatically is surely something I'd need to understand before I realize the absurdity of my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: you can't!

In case the super class has a parameter free constructor, the compiler can add one like that for you in subclass, too.

But when the super class needs parameters, the compiler has no idea where these should come from.

So: consider adding a no args constructor to the super class, it could invoke the other constructor and pass some sort of default values. Alternatively, you can do the same in the derived class.

And just for the record: there are no Java classes without constructors. It is just that the compiler might create one for you behind the covers. From that point of view, your question does not make much sense.

Comment: Why can't I just write the line super("text"); or super.A("text"); in class B without a constructor? Wouldn't the compiler know the value to pass to the parameter then?

Comment: Because you can't. That are the rules. The keyword "super" can only be used as first statement within a constructor. It isn't allowed anywhere else. Learn the basic rules of Java, instead of trying to invent your own rules! Beyond that, any statements need to be in the body of a method, you can't just put them anywhere in a class.

Comment: @MatthewS. because constructors are called at the time of object construction.. if you call super elsewhere, it would be too late

Comment: Good point: there is a clearly defined order how objects get initialized upon creation!

Comment: @GhostCat the keyword "super" can be used in any method of the child class, anywhere, as long as it's in a method. Also a simple "I don't know" would of sufficed instead of insinuating that I'm trying to come up with my own rules. I'm only trying to understand java like the back of hand, which is why I'm asking such specific questions.

Comment: @MatthewS. there's a difference between `super` and `super()`.. the later would call the constructor, so you can only put it in the first line of the constructor, not anywhere else

Answer (score 2):

You are getting compilation error because there is no default constructor in class `A`. You can create a no-arg constructor in `B` and pass some default text to `A`'s contructor, or create a no-arg constructor in `A`.

```
public B() {
    super("some default text"); //will call public A(String text)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if it's possible to call the constructor in class A from class B, without creating a constructor in class B.

Comment: You misunderstood his question. He knows why he's getting the compilation error.

Comment: @MatthewS. it's not possible

Comment: @MatthewS. Constructors are not like instance methods. The constructor must be invoked to create an object. Then you can call any method *on* that object. You cannot move invoking the parent constructor part (`super(..)`) to any method as you need an object first to invoke the method(Kind of chicken and egg problem).. You are out of luck when thinking of static methods too. There is no *instance* or *object* associated with a static method. So, `super` does not work there.

Comment: @MatthewS. Sorry, you are correct. I meant super in the context of calling a super class constructor. super() is something completely different than super.someMethod()!

Comment: I know. To get the @ thing working, I need to switch to "desktop page" which is really terrible to use on the mobile phone. But he was still notified about the comment, so I will go in and delete it later here :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to call the parent constructor directly, you'll just need to add a constructor with the same parameters in the child class that just calls the parent constructor.

```
public class A { 
    public String text; 

    public A(String text) 
    { 
        this.text = text; 
    } 
} 

public class B extends A 
{
    public B(String text)
    {
        super(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is *"calling the parent constructor directly"* if not this?

Comment: I interpreted the question as misunderstanding why `B foo = new B("test");` wouldn't work (without defining a constructor in B) and expecting it just to call the parent constructor directly.